# how declare xml-element in xsd-schema

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd

I have xml with elements:

```
<attribute name="attributeName1" 
           type="typeName1">value1</attribute>
...
<attribute name="attributeName2" 
           type="typeName2">
    <row order="1">
        <attribute name="attributeName3" 
                   type="typeName3">value3</attribute>
        ...
    </row>
    ...
 </attribute>
```

How these elements can by declared in xsd-schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the `attribute` element so that it has a type with mixed content. Like the following:

```
<xsd:element name="attribute">
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    ...
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

This is going to give you a JAXB class something like the following where you end up with one property that will store both the text and `Row` objects.

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "attribute")
public class Attribute {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "row", namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;

}
```

You will probably be happier in the long run if you do something like the following instead.

```
<attribute name="attributeName1" type="typeName1">
    <value>value1</value>
</attribute>
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply :)